How can I generate instances on my imported svg logo file using geometry nodes?
I have imported an svg file of a logo and I need to generate a crowd of people that essentially "form the logo" from a top view.  I've been able to create a geometry node where I can generate the crowd instances on a grid mesh, but I don't know how I can do the same thing with using the svg logo file?
